# How to make archive of drupal database

Tags: database

How to make archive of drupal database with a php code inside node? Without any scripts. This needs in case you forget your FTP access.

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clearer? I have no clue what you are trying to do and what your problem is.

Comment: For example: i have a user with id==1, how can i make a copy of site's database using php code inside a node, then download it. In case i've forgot ftp and phpmyadmin logins.

Answer (score 3):

There is a module for this, use that instead of custom coding PHP in nodes. Generally you never want to put code in nodes for a lot of reasons:

- No version control.
- If you make a syntax error you're in big troubles.
- very hard to maintain when you need to upgrade a site (API changes).
- Greater possibility to open your site for security vulnerabilities.
- ...

Anyways the module [backup and migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) will do what you need.

**Alternative solution**

If you don't have DB password or FTP password and want to create a dump, the simplest thing you can do it to:

1. get the DB password from Drupal

   ```
   global $db_url;
   drupal_set_message($db_url);
   ```
2. Use the password obtained from Drupal to login to PHPmyadmin or similar
3. Use the GUI to create the dump.

Comment: Sorry, but i won't use a module for that task. So you have no idea about this?

Comment: @Heihachi You can copy/paste the code from the module. But after seeing what's needed you might want to reconsider. Any reason why you don't want to use a module?

Comment: in order to install a module, you need FTP access, which the OP has not.

Comment: @Heihachi If you don't have the passwords needed, check my alternative solution.

Comment: I have database password, database name and host adress. But i cant login to phpmyadmin, because i can't find the link